# Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType' - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to reverse string in Swift 2.0 but I get an error on the string ifself.

```
func reverseString(string: String) -> String {
    var buffer = ""
    for character in string {
        buffer.insert(character, atIndex: buffer.startIndex)
    }

    return buffer
}
```

The error:

```
Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
func reverseString(string: String) -> String {
    return String(string.characters.reverse())
}
```

Your code works with this change

```
for character in string.characters {
```

**Swift 3:**

In Swift 3 `reverse()` has been renamed to `reversed()`

**Swift 4:**

In Swift 4 `characters` can be omitted because `String` returned to behave like a sequence.

```
func reverseString(string: String) -> String {
    return String(string.reversed())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 2, `String` doesn't conform to `SequenceType`.

You can add an extension.

```
extension String: SequenceType {}
```

Comment: Note: SequenceType' has been renamed to 'Sequence'. Conformance of 'String' to protocol 'Sequence' was already stated in the type's module 'Swift'